# how to compare time slots?

Tags: sql-server

I have a table called `pricelist`

```
startHour
endHour
Price
```

and another table that containes the `actualuse`

```
startDate
endDate
jobID
```

My data is

```
pricelist

startHour | endHour | price
----------------------------
00:00     | 07:59   | 10
08:00     | 15:59   | 20
16:00     | 23:59   | 5

actualUse

startDate        | endDate         | jobId
-------------------------------------------
12/10/2014 08:30 | 12/10/2014 15:20| 1
12/10/2014 07:30 | 12/10/2014 18:20| 2
12/10/2014 07:30 | 13/10/2014 16:20| 3
12/10/2014 09:30 | 13/10/2014 00:20| 4
```

I am trying to get, for every job, all rows in `pricelist` that belong to it. For example for jobId 1 I will get

```
startDate        | endDate         | jobId  |price
---------------------------------------------------
12/10/2014 08:30 | 12/10/2014 15:20| 1      |10
```

for jobId 2

```
startDate        | endDate         | jobId  |price
---------------------------------------------------
12/10/2014 07:30 | 12/10/2014 07:59| 2      |10    
12/10/2014 08:00 | 12/10/2014 15:59| 2      |20
12/10/2014 16:00 | 12/10/2014 18:20| 2      |5
```

for jobId 3

```
startDate        | endDate         | jobId  |price
---------------------------------------------------
12/10/2014 07:30 | 12/10/2014 07:59| 3      |10
12/10/2014 08:00 | 12/10/2014 15:59| 3      |20
12/10/2014 16:00 | 12/10/2014 23:59| 3      |5
13/10/2014 00:00 | 13/10/2014 07:59| 3      |10
13/10/2014 08:00 | 13/10/2014 15:59| 3      |20
13/10/2014 16:00 | 13/10/2014 16:20| 3      |5
```

Comment: I don't understand this at all. You seem to have no actual relation between `pricelist` and `actualuse`

Comment: Are all your times always exact minutes?

Comment: Shouldn't the sample output for jobId 1 have a price of 20?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interesting problem. I'd use a `calendar` table:

```
calendar

calendar_date
--------------
2014-01-01
2014-01-02
...
2014-12-01
2014-12-02
..
2014-12-31
2015-01-01
...
```

and restructure the `pricelist` to use closed-open intervals, instead of closed ones:

```
pricelist

startHour | endHour | price
----------------------------
00:00     | 08:00   | 10
08:00     | 16:00   | 20
16:00     | 24:00   | 5
```

It would not work exactly as it is above because `TIME` datatype cannot hold the value of `24:00:00` hours, so you probably have to use datetime. (In the linked example, I used `datetime2(0)` but I think it would work with `datetime` as well.

Then you could use this query to check for overlapping intervals between your `pricelist (statDate, enddate)` intervals and the ones calculated from the `calendar` and the `pricelist` values:

```
SELECT 
    startDate = CASE WHEN a.startDate < x.startD THEN x.startD ELSE a.startDate END,  -- max
    endDate = CASE WHEN a.endDate < x.endD THEN a.endDate ELSE x.endD END,            -- min
    a.jobID,
    p.price
FROM actualUse AS a
  CROSS JOIN calendar AS c
  CROSS JOIN pricelist AS p
  CROSS APPLY
    ( SELECT
          startD = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,'19000101',c.calendar_date), p.startHour),
          endD = DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day,'19000101',c.calendar_date), p.endHour)
     ) AS x 
WHERE a.startDate < x.endD
  AND x.startD < a.endDate ;
```

The complicated `DATEADD(day, DATEDIFF(day, ...)` expression is there for adding a `DATE` and a `DATETIME` value:

SQL-Fiddle is down today, but (thank you SO!) [we can test at dba.se Data Explorer](http://data.stackexchange.com/dba/query/251631/compare-time-slots)

Answer (score 3):

Apologies for the slightly Heath Robinson presentation. Hopefully the below will give you some pointers nonetheless.

I'm using a "numbers" table.  There are any number of aricles on the interwebs explaining what this is, why it's a good thing and how to get one efficiently.

I take the `pricelist` columns to be `time(0)` and `actualUse` as `smalldatetime`.  Other types would work with suitable adjustments to the respective functions.

You don't say what version of SQL Server.  I've written for 2008R2 since that's what I had to hand.  Newer versions have nicer syntax for some of the things I've done.

I've laid it out as a series of CTEs simply because that's how the ideas came to me and what I could manage in the time available.  Undoubtedly further thought would give a prettier, simpler, more effieient structure.  This would not be resilient against anomolies in `pricelist`.  Any gaps or overlaps would cause all sorts of problems with my solution.  Your examples had a job lasting, at most, overnight.  This will cover a job of any duration.

Anyhoo, thanks for the challenge!

```
;with OrderedPrices as
(
    -- Add an ordinal to the prices; this will be JOINed to later.
    select
        p.*
        ,ROW_NUMBER() over (order by p.startHour) - 1 as rn
    from pricelist as p
)
,ExpandedPrices as
(
    -- repeat pricelist off into the future, as far as necessary
    select
        e.startHour,
        e.endHour,
        e.Price,
        n.n/(select COUNT(*)from pricelist) as DaySequence,
        e.rn as PriceSequence
    from OrderedPrices as e
    inner join numbers as n    -- numbers must start from zero for this to work.
        on e.rn = (n.n % (select COUNT(*)from pricelist))
    where n.n < 1000   -- maximum number of outputs expected for one job.
                       -- too small = lost values; too large = wasted CPU cycles.
                       -- could be automated by looking at actualUse.
)
, JobDays as
(
    -- Create one row for each calendar day a job touches.
    select
        a.startDate,
        a.endDate,
        a.JobID,
        n.n as DaySequence
    from actualuse as a
    inner join numbers as n
        on n.n <= DATEDIFF(day,a.startdate,a.enddate)
)
,JobPrices as
(
    -- Bring together the expanded lists and match on the ordinals created above.
    select
        DATEADD(DAY, jd.DaySequence,
            DATEADD(minute, datepart(minute, ep.startHour),
            DATEADD(hour, datepart(hour, ep.startHour),
            dateadd(day, DATEPART(day, jd.startDate) - 1, 
            dateadd(month, datepart(month, jd.startDate) - 1, 
            dateadd(year, datepart(year, jd.startDate) - 1900, 0)))))) as PriceStartDateTime,
        DATEADD(DAY, jd.DaySequence,
            DATEADD(minute, datepart(minute, ep.endHour),
            DATEADD(hour, datepart(hour, ep.endHour),
            dateadd(day, DATEPART(day, jd.startDate) - 1, 
            dateadd(month, datepart(month, jd.startDate) - 1, 
            dateadd(year, datepart(year, jd.startDate) - 1900, 0)))))) as PriceEndDateTime,
        ep.startHour,
        ep.endHour,
        ep.Price,
        ep.DaySequence,
        ep.PriceSequence,
        jd.startDate,
        jd.endDate,
        jd.JobID
    from ExpandedPrices as ep
    inner join JobDays as jd
        on jd.DaySequence = ep.DaySequence
)
select
    -- The earlier of job start or price band start.
    case
        when jp.PriceStartDateTime < jp.startDate
            then jp.startDate
        else jp.PriceStartDateTime
    end as startDate,
    -- the later of job end or price band end.
    case
        when jp.PriceEndDateTime > jp.endDate
            then jp.endDate
        else jp.PriceEndDateTime
    end as endDate,
    jp.JobID,
    jp.Price
from JobPrices as jp
where jp.PriceStartDateTime <= jp.endDate
and jp.PriceEndDateTime >= jp.startDate
order by
    jp.JobID,
    jp.DaySequence,
    jp.PriceSequence;
```